# Unrecognized option "oauth" under "security.firewalls.primary"

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

I'm trying to install an old legacy system from a company I'm freelancing for, but I keep getting

> InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309: Unrecognized
>   option "oauth" under "security.firewalls.primary"

This code supposedly runs without errors elsewhere is there anything I'm missing? Here's my security.yml where there error is probably in:

```
imports:
    - { resource: ../../../_common/config/security.yml }

security:
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|bundles|assets)/
            security: false

        login:
            context:   primary
            pattern:   ^/account/login/$
            anonymous: true

        anonymous:
            context:   primary
            pattern:   ^/account/(register|login/reset-password).*
            anonymous: true

        primary:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path:    UserBundle:Front:loginCheck
                login_path:    UserBundle:Front:login
                remember_me:   true
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            remember_me:
                key:      '%secret%'
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~

            logout:
                path:   UserBundle:Front:logout
                target: UserBundle:Front:login

            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: /account/connect/check-facebook/
                    twitter:  /account/connect/check-twitter/

                login_path:   UserBundle:Front:login
                failure_path: UserBundle:Front:logout

                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: user.oauth.manager

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/account/(login|register|connect), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Do you use a specific bundle for authentification ? In first idea I'll say : Have you include the oauth bundle in your app/kernel ?

Comment: The system uses
"hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev"

I suppose it's included as it's running live (unfortunately at the moment I don't have access to it)
On a quick look at the AppKernel.php I can't find it though.

Comment: That's maybe the problem, if your bundle is not registered in the appkernel, it doesn't know how to interpret this option in the security.yml

Comment: Could you give me some guidance on how to do that? I'm new to Symfony, should I put it on the function registerBundles()?
And if yes, what should I put?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md

Comment: You're a legend, thanks man.
I got to a second error though:
The child node "resource_owners" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured.

I found how to do it on the link you gave me, however it just tells me to put on the routing.yml, I did a search and the project has got 42 routing.yml.

Is there a way to know which one is the right? I have placed in a few and no joy so far

Comment: app/config/routing.yml.

Comment: Yep, legend, thanks!

But there's more
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "hwi_oauth_redirect" (in /var/www/html/spaceports/testing/local/admin/app/config/../../../_common/config/../../_system/config/config.yml). Looked for namespace "hwi_oauth_redirect",...

I'm thinking it's because of the "@" that's on the link you've given me
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"

I went to the vendor folder and the file is there, is there a way to point directly instead of using @HWIOAuth... something like "/vendor/hwi..."?

Comment: hwi_oauth_redirect  ? It should be in routing.yml not in config.yml

Comment: Dammit, then I'm back to

The child node "resource_owners" at path "hwi_oauth" must be configured.

Comment: Lol infinite loop. You have to set up the owners when installing this bundle, facebook or google, or just the older you have... I can't help you more.... It seems like the sources you have are not synchro with the production...

Comment: Are you some kind of witch?
That's exactly it, they had given me a document telling me to working a branch but they are actually working in another branch.

Thanks man